# Storing MomentJS objects in MongoDB vs. MongoLab

Tags: javascript, mongodb, momentjs, mlab

I know it's not recommended to store MomentJS objects in databases (although I don't really understand why).  I'm having some bizarre problems storing them: my local MongoDB vs. the remote MongoLab seem to be outputting slightly different date/times (is this because of timezone difference?).

---

For example:

When I save: `moment(1 + '-' + 2014, 'Q-YYYY')`

**MongoLab:**  `1388534400000`

**Local MongoDB:** `1388563200000`

That difference comes out to 8 hours.

---

In order to fix this problem, should I convert my Moment objects to ISO strings with `.toISOString()`?  I'm also interested in why this problem happens, if anyone has the answer to that.

Comment: Have you tried setting an explicit timezone?

Comment: No, I'm not sure how to do that.  Isn't that more of a round-about fix, instead of not storing moment objects in the DB in the first place?

Comment: It's mostly due to the timezone in your local machine and the TZ in the MongoLab's server.

Comment: So what's the accepted way of fixing this?  Should I have different code on my local v. remote?  Or is there a way to standardize the times across timezones?

Comment: You can standardise on a timezone like GMT and use [`moment.timezone`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/). However, if you only need to store `Q-YYYY` then perhaps you only want to save that string rather than a Date object that has to be re-parsed.